# Can we have a while loop logic in Task.Run?

Tags: c#

I want to do something like:

```
Task.Run(while(true)
{
doSomething()
}
```

Is there a proper way of doing this?

Comment: um wouldn't this be better for a real thread? you could do it but pass a lambda.

Comment: Sure, why not? But there might be a better way to do what you are trying to do. If you explain why you want this, maybe SO can provide a better solution

Comment: I'm doing this inside OpenAsync and spawning another thread will help with not blocking OpenAsync. I am just not sure how to format the lambda using while(true).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Task.Run(() => {
    while (true) {
        doSomething();
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add some other options.

1. The task creation option should indicate that this is a long running thread.
2. You may want to include a task cancellation token to allow this thread to terminate.